# Custom Pivot Table name giving error no such table:main

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Implementing many to many relationships with custom Pivot table name is giving error.

**Service.php Model**

```
class Service extends Model
{
  public function categories()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\ServiceCategory', 'category_service');
  }
}
```

**ServiceCategory.php Model**

```
class ServiceCategory extends Model
{
  public function services()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service', 'category_service');
  }
}
```

**Table Names**

1. services
2. service_categories
3. **category_service (Pivot Table Name)**

Test

```
class RelationshipTest extends TestCase
{
  use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function a_service_can_belong_to_many_categories()
    {
      $service = factory(Service::class)->create();
      $category = factory(ServiceCategory::class)->create();

      $service->categories()->sync($category);

      $this->assertEquals(1, $service->first()->categories()->count());
      $this->assertInstanceOf('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection', $service->categories);
    }
}
```

The test is giving this error.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: main.categories
```

How to use custom pivot table name without getting this error.

Comment: pass third and fourth argument to the relationship containing foreign key of the related models. and check if that works.

Comment: in your ServiceCategory model try adding this line:
 protected $table = 'yourTableName';

Comment: @OMR Thanks. Applied your suggestion. However, the error remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message and the issue came from my migration's foreign key constrains.

I forgot to override the default `constrained()` table name ("categories") to this:

```php
Schema::create('category_service', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // ...
    $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained('service_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    // ..
});
```